# “404 error: Page not found” without doing any changes. Backend works fine

Tags: magento-1.8

[image: error]

I do not know what happend to the website. The only thing I did was that I flushed the cache of the website hoping to make it faster. Please help me identify what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Check your `core_website` and `core_store` tables. Do you have a `store_id`'s `0` and `1`?  Sometimes a bad import will mess with these auto increments.

What store code are you setting?  In `index.php` try setting changing the last line to

```
var_dump($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

Does the `$mageRunCode` exist in `core_store.code`?